# Angular2 - using class binding to check data creates many calls

Tags: angular, ngfor

I’m new to Angular 2 (and StackOverflow) and may be using class binding in an inappropriate way. I wanted to check with the experts.

I have a ngFor loop which displays data from an array of several objects. Within each of those objects is an array of users. I want to change the class of each data item if the user is logged in.

In the example below I’ve just hard coded the user as a public variable.

Within my ngFor loop I’m calling a function (“checkUser”) from the class binding and passing in the current data item. The function checkUser will search for the logged in user inside the data item and return true or false. If true is returned it will set the item’s class to active. If false, the class stays at the default which is inactive.

This works in that the class does change if the user is found.

**However I’m finding each item is making 3 calls to checkUser whenever the ngFor loop updates.** I can't figure out why this happens and if it *should* be happening.

Most likely I'm doing something wrong and would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div class = "inactive" *ngFor = "let data of exampleData"
        [class.active] = "checkUser(data)">
        {{data.desc}}
    </div>
    `,
  styles: [`
    .inactive {
      color: grey;
    }
    .active {
      color: red;
    }
  `]
})

export class ClassTestComponent {

  public user = 'Bob';
  public exampleData: Array<any> = [{
        _id: '0',
        desc: 'The user is tied to this data',
        users: ['Bob', 'Jim']
      },
      {
         _id: '1',
         desc: 'The user is not tied to this data',
         users: ['Sue', 'May']
       }];

  checkUser(data): boolean {

    if (data.users.includes(this.user)) {
        console.log('user in array');
        return true;
     } else {
        console.log('user not in array');
        return false;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are applying class on element is decrease the performance of application. We should avoid to call function from a view.

The function checkUser(data) function will be called every time Angular runs change detection for the component (more precisely for the embedded view created by ngFor). This is because updating DOM is part of change detection and Angular needs to call checkUser to know what value to use for DOM update. And change detection cycle can run quite often.

Instead of that you can use this code:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of exampleData" [ngClass]="(data.users.indexOf(user) > -1 ) ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
{{data.desc}}
```

Read more about how Angular updates DOM in [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d)

I hope this will help you.